# Apache mina await vs awaitUninterruptibly

Tags: java, apache-mina

What is the difference between the 2 methods ? In which case one should be used over the other ?

```
/**
 * Wait for the asynchronous operation to complete with the specified timeout.
 *
 * @return <tt>true</tt> if the operation is completed.
 */
boolean await(long timeoutMillis) throws InterruptedException;
```

Versus

```
/**
 * Wait for the asynchronous operation to complete with the specified timeout
 * uninterruptibly.
 *
 * @return <tt>true</tt> if the operation is finished.
 */
boolean awaitUninterruptibly(long timeoutMillis);
```

Comment: Do you know what an `interrupt` is?

Comment: thread.interrupt(); ?

Comment: So now you know that one will ignore this call/flag and the other will throw an exception.

Comment: Doesn't seem to make sense at all.

Comment: Perhaps you are overthinking it. Tell yourself it is very simple. ;)